# How to get the complete code for braintree in codename one

Tags: codenameone, braintree

Pls is the code below is enough to handle braintree for payment?

```
Purchase.startOrder(new Purchase.Callback() {


public String fetchToken() {

return "";

}

public void onPurchaseSuccess(String nonce) {

}

public void onPurchaseFail(String errorMessage) {

}
public void onPurchaseCancel() {

}
});
```

For the sample test I return the token provided in braintree websites like this

```
     Purchase.startOrder(new Purchase.Callback() {
public String fetchToken() {
return "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";

}



public void onPurchaseSuccess(String nonce) {

}

public void onPurchaseFail(String errorMessage) {

}
public void onPurchaseCancel() {

}
});
```

When I buit and install on my phone to test it out. It displays the payment method which include paypal and add debit or credit card.

**When I want to integrate my own:**
The problem am facing now is that at the server side, I have a code that provides client token
My questions: 
1. How do I call this token in codename one, although I have code that says `return "";`. What am I going to return here? I pointed the url that generated the token inside the return. It didn't work.
2. If I get my own token is that enough to handle the payment? according to the code provided above.
3. Is ssl required on the server side I want to use? 
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/braintree-paypal-cn1lib.html) you need to have a server to implement payments. Instructions of implementing the server are in the braintree website which is [linked too](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview).

Just look in the server section there and implement that. You then need to return the token generated in the server to your client code.