# android build error on codenameone with braintree payments

Tags: codenameone, braintree

when I add braintree extension to my codenameone project and send android build to codenameone I got build error with these error log:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'NLApplication'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
 Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
     file:/tmp/build2388050053529696565xxx/NLApplication/libs/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
     file:/tmp/build2388050053529696565xxx/NLApplication/libs/cardview-v7.jar
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
 Required by:
     :NLApplication:unspecified > com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.1.0
Could not find com.android.support:design:26.0.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar
     file:/tmp/build2388050053529696565xxx/NLApplication/libs/design-26.0.0.jar
     file:/tmp/build2388050053529696565xxx/NLApplication/libs/design.jar
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.pom
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.pom
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar
 Required by:
     :NLApplication:unspecified > com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.1.0 > com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.1.0
```

Comment: Initial thoughts...[this repo](https://github.com/codenameone/BraintreeCodenameOne) _may_ be relevant to your endeavor. You may also want to reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44104489/5326365) from a Codename One co-founder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Braintree pushed out a 3.1 update with an odd new dependency that fails. I've restricted gradle to use 3.0 and will push out an updated cn1lib. This should appear as an update in your extension manager later today. However, if you have the cn1lib already installed you will need to first delete the build hint `android.gradleDep` then do a refresh cn1libs.